# Do you know of a Windows app that's similar to Cyberduck?

Tags: windows, file-transfer

I need a desktop app that I can run on my Windows server that will give me access to files from:

- S3
- Rackspace cloud
- Google docs
- FTP

That's what Cyberduck gives me access to right now.

Essentially, what I'd like to do is copy & move files from one of those services to the others.

Comment: I might be pointing out the obvious here, but you are going to have to transfer the files to your computer as an intermediary (cyberduck does it transparently for you).  So wouldn't it be possible to just copy the files to your compute then upload them using the normal interface?

Comment: @Daisetsu, you are most probably right, but maybe some of these services supports [FXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol)? Or, if the protocols of these services are really not FTP, then *maybe* there's something similar to FXP for those protocols?

Comment: (Maybe describing the protocols in the title, rather than referring to Cyberduck, will get you help from non-Mac users.)

Answer (score 2):

Cyberduck will be available for Windows really soon. Cyberduck for Windows boasts the same features as its OS X counterpart and will be developed in parallel from now on. For more information and to sign up for the Private Beta refer to the [blog entry](http://sudo.ch/2010/08/25/cyberduck-for-windows-is-coming/).

Comment: CyberDuck is now and has been available for Windows for a while now.